# Flexslide custom navigation

Tags: jquery, html, flexslider

I am trying to create a custom navigation bar that links to specific slides in Flexslider using the

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider(0); });
```

function but to no avail. I have 4 links with individual id's,

```
<a class="homelink 1" id="#slide1" href="#"></a>
<a class="headerlink 2" id="#slide2" href="#">About Us</a>
<a class="headerlink 3" id="#slide3" href="#">Gallery</a>
<a class="headerlink 4" id="#slide4" href="#">Contact</a>
```

using this bit of script

```
$("#slide1").click(function() { $('.flexslider').flexslider(0); });
$("#slide2").click(function() { $('.flexslider').flexslider(1); });
$("#slide3").click(function() { $('.flexslider').flexslider(2); });
$("#slide4").click(function() { $('.flexslider').flexslider(3); });
```

Finger swipe and keyboard navigation works fine. Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks!!